# " text-underline-offset" not working in "display: block"

Tags: html, css

Here's my code

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation .active {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation container">
  <div class="nav-brand">iAmADeveloper</div>
  <ul class="list-non-bullet nav-pills">
    <li class="list-inline-item active"><a class="link" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="link" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="link" href="blogs.html">Blogs</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Whenever I am setting the .link to display: inline-block, the text-underline-offset: 5px; style is not working and is shown in white color in VS Code. But, when I remove the display: inline-block, it works fine.
I need my links to be underlined when hovered. How to fix this?
PS: I am not implementing JS in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `a`

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation .active a{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation container">
  <div class="nav-brand">iAmADeveloper</div>
  <ul class="list-non-bullet nav-pills">
    <li class="list-inline-item active"><a class="link" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="link" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="link" href="blogs.html">Blogs</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine now. I wonder why it was not working well earlier.

Comment: @SaadAhmad because you were targeting the `li` element and you simply had luck because the initial display of `li` make it working which is not the case when using `inline-block`. If you target `a` it will work whataver the display of `li`